# How do I clear the selection in a ButtonGroup such that no elements of the associated set of abstract buttons are selected?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I have created 5 radioButton group. I want user clear all group in one click.
i use java 1.5.

**Does any one know how to do it?**

```
public void actionCommandCLEAR() {
        timeGroup.setSelected(timeGroup.getSelection(),false);
        dateGroup.setSelected(dateGroup.getSelection(),false);
        docGroup.setSelected(docGroup.getSelection(),false);
        socGroup.setSelected(socGroup.getSelection(),false);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
timeGroup.clearSelection();
dateGroup.clearSelection();
docGroup.clearSelection();
socGroup.clearSelection();
```

for java 1.5 we need to code clearSelection ourselves:

```
void cleartSelection(ButtonGroup bg) {
 Enumeration<AbstractButton> e =bg.getElements(); 
    while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
        AbstractButton b = e.nextElement();
        b.setSelected(false);
    }
}
```

and

```
clearSelection(timeGroup);
```

Comment: My fault, edited for java 1.5

Comment: Sorry to say but it does not changed the state. can be that i should refresh or update GUI

Comment: that doesn't work - the pre1.6 implementation of buttonGroup simply ignores the very last setSelected(false).

Answer (score 2):

I just add one extra hidden radio-button to every group and select that one when i want to clear all buttonsGroup.

```
public void actionCommandCLEAR() {
        hiddenTime.setSelected(true);
        hiddenDate.setSelected(true);
        hiddenDoc.setSelected(true);
        hiddenSoc.setSelected(true);
        hiddenLand.setSelected(true);
    }
```

Comment: Good enough a hack for the missing functionality :-) Alternatively, you could extend ButtonGroup and implement the clearSelection.

Answer (score 1):

this is reason for why is created [Select Button Group](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/09/select-button-group/) by @Darryl Burke

Comment: no, that's not the point: the question was about _clearing_ the selected, not about accessing the selected button. Prior to 1.6 it was not possible to have all models unselected (except at instantiation time).